# How to create a calculated column in access that is based in a conditional sum of another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

It is possible in MS ACCESS 2016 to create a column in a table that is a conditional SUM of another table?

Example

Table 1 - Columns

```
ID, NAME, TOTAL
```

Table 2 - Columns

```
ID, NAME, IDREF, CUSTO
```

Data:

Table 1

```
ID | Name  | Total
---+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------
35 |  Test |  "SUM(CUSTO) of ALL ELEMENTS OF TABLE 2 WHERE table2.IDREF = table1.ID"
```

Table 2

```
ID | Name  | IDREF | CUSTO
---+-------+-------+--------
1  | Test  |  35   |   50
2  | Test  |  35   |   30
3  | abcd  |  12   |   30
4  | Test  |  35   |   10
```

The result should be:

table 1

```
ID | Name | Total
---+------+------
35 | Test |  90      (50 + 30 + 10 from table 2 where idref = 35)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select sum(t2.CUSTO)
        from table2 as t2
        where t2.idref = t1.id
       ) as total
from table1 as t1;
```

Comment: With some modifications it worked! 

The Expression:

"SELECT t1.id,(SELECT SUM(CUSTO) FROM t2 WHERE t2.IDREF=t1.id) AS TOTAL
FROM t1;"

Answer (score 1):

More efficiently, consider an aggregate subquery in `JOIN` to run only *once* and not `SELECT` subquery that runs for *every* row.

```
SELECT t1.*, agg.Total
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN
   ( SELECT t2.idref, SUM(t2.CUSTO) AS Total
     FROM table2 as t2
     GROUP BY t2.idref
   ) AS agg
ON agg.idref = t1.id
```

Alternatively, replace subquery with exact saved query for even more efficiency per Allen Browne's [optimizing query tips in MS Access](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html):

> A subquery will be considerably faster than a domain aggregate function. In most cases, a **stacked query will be faster yet** (i.e. another saved query that you include as a "table" in this query.)

```
SELECT t1.*, q.Total
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN mySavedAggQuery q
ON q.idref = t1.id
```